# import_type attempt to call global

Tags: c#, lua, luainterface

I'm using the latest lua interface and trying to run this code

```
luanet.load_assembly("Phoenix")
luanet.load_assembly("Phoenix.Structures")
NpcDialog = luanet.import_type("Phoenix.Structures.NpcDialog")

function npc(request, client)
    local dialog = new NpcDialog(client)
    dialog.Text("hi this is a test")
    dialog.Send()
end
```

but getting this error 
LuaInterface.LuaException: [string "chunk"]:6: attempt to call global 'NpcDialog
' (a nil value)

the exe name is `Map Server.exe`

Assembly name `Map Server`
Default namespace `Phoenix`

it happens because the the assembly of the file different than the Assembly name and i don't know why!!

is there a way to make it work without changing the Assembly name

Comment: are you saying that you have an assembly name `MapServer.dll` which has namespace Phoenix in it?

Comment: Yes, Assembly name Map Server and the namespace for the type is Phoenix.Structures.NpcDialog

Answer (score 1):

There is no `new` operator in Lua. Write:

```
function npc(request, client)
    local dialog = NpcDialog(client)
```

If you still get same problem after this fix, then `NpcDialog` is nil: maybe return value of import is nil, or maybe it gets nilled between the import line and the line that calls `npc(r,c)`. Maybe try

```
assert( NpcDialog )
```

If this fails meaning that `load_assembly("Phoenix")` failed, it's probably because the assembly is not called "Phoenix" but "Map Server", so try

```
luanet.load_assembly("Map Server")
NpcDialog = luanet.import_type("Phoenix.Structures.NpcDialog")
assert(NpcDialog)
```

Comment: @AtefRamadan You sure it is exact same error (same line and all)?

Answer (score 0):

Line 6 is valid Lua code but it does not do what you think. Lua parses it as if there was a ; after `new`, and so tries to call `NpcDialog`.

Comment: @AtefRamadan, I don't know LuaInterface, sorry. And I don't understand why `NpcDialog` is nil.